# Drop factor level with few observations

Tags: r

I used table() to crosstab `factor.one` (with levels `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`) by `factor.two` (with levels `0` and `1`). I want to drop a level in `factor.one` if it has less than 5 counts of level `1` in `factor.two`

In the example code below, I loop through a third factor variable called `location` to create these tables. I'm using this to build a dynamic formula for a survival model that only includes levels of categorical variables with more than 5 counts of an event.

Some data:

```
factor.one <- factor(c(rep("A", 20), rep("B", 25), rep("C", 30), rep("D", 37))) 
factor.two <- factor(c(rep(1, 10), rep(0, 10), rep(1, 4), rep(0, 21), rep(1, 15), rep(1, 15), rep(1, 15), rep(0, 22)))
location <-c(rep("US", 60), rep("Canada", 52))
df <- data.frame(factor.one, factor.two, location)
```

What I've tried so far:

```
test <- lapply(unique(df$location), function(x) {
  
  sub.df <- dplyr::filter(df, location == x) 
  
  sub.table <- table(sub.df$factor.one, sub.df$factor.two)
  
  sub.names.to.drop <- rownames(sub.table)[sub.table[, 2] < 5]
   
  sub.dropped <- sub.df[!any(levels(sub.df$factor.one)) %in% sub.names.to.drop]
  
  return(sub.dropped)
  
})
```

If you run the code above, you'll see a list of two tables. For example, in the first table, levels `B` and `D` should be dropped. In the second table, levels `A` and `B` should be dropped.

I haven't been able to figure out the last two lines.. the last line doesn't seem to be dropping any of the levels with < 5 observations. I'm not sure how to subset `sub.df` to drop the levels in `sub.names.to.drop`. Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `any` in the last line and also no need to drop by levels. Try the following :

```
test <- lapply(unique(df$location), function(x) {
  sub.df <- dplyr::filter(df, location == x) 
  sub.table <- table(sub.df$factor.one, sub.df$factor.two)
  sub.names.to.drop <- rownames(sub.table)[sub.table[, 2] < 5]
  sub.dropped <- sub.df[!sub.df$factor.one %in% sub.names.to.drop, ]
  return(droplevels(sub.dropped))
})
```